# HTML Conteneditable - join paragraphs without inline styles being applied

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable

In a WYSIWYG editor (based on a *contenteditable* div), I have code to make sure that no inline styles are inserted into the HTML while copy-pasting, normal typing, etc. But now browsers seem to want to screw with me even more. Say I have 2 paragraphs of this sort in my HTML

```
<p>This is the first paragraph |(cursor)</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
```

There are no inline styles present. But if I now join the two paragraphs by pressing "*Delete/Backspace*", Chrome decides to do this

```
<p>This is the first paragraph |(cursor)
    <!-- Note the horrible inline styles -->
    <span style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 19.53px;">
        This is the second paragraph
    </span>
</p>
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how I might prevent/detect when this happens?

Comment: Can't replicate (in Chrome). http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/HHHak/1/ Both paragraphs end up being one paragraph with no other tags applied. Can you please provide a Fiddle showing this issue?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Let me get back to you on this. It might be a code issue. Thank you for the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Webkit's issue. It also influences CKEditor (http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9998). I reported these tickets:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226941
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114791

But there was no response.

You could not replicate this on jsfiddle because styles need to be applied to those paragraphs. E.g.:

```
p { line-height: 1.5em; font-size: 12px; }
```

Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/HHHak/2/

So currently there are two possible solutions:

- avoid any styling :| (but that won't solve other issues I described in mentioned bug reports),
- implement your own backspace/delete support (really tricky... you can find [an algorithm in a spec draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-delete-command), but I'm not certain that it is complete).

Comment: holy mother! I was going along a completely different track. I am so glad you took the time to point this out. I'll let you know what progress I make on this.

Comment: Does the CKEditor have its own backspace/delete handler?

Comment: Not yet. But we're planning to add it.